# Reading in file with delimiter

Tags: c++, file-io, struct

How do I read in lines from a file and assign specific segments of that line to the information in structs? And how can I stop at a blank line, then continue again until end of file is reached?

Background: I am building a program that will take an input file, read in information, and use double hashing for that information to be put in the correct index of the hashtable.

Suppose I have the struct:

```
struct Data
{
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipCode;
};
```

But the lines in the file are in the following format:

```
20

85086,Phoenix,Arizona
56065,Minneapolis,Minnesota

85281
56065
```

Sorry but I still cannot seem to figure this out. I am having a really hard time reading in the file. The first line is basically the size of the hash table to be constructed. The next blank line should be ignored. Then the next two lines are information that should go into the struct and be hashed into the hash table. Then another blank line should be ignored. And finally, the last two lines are input that need to be matched to see if they exist in the hash table or not. So in this case, 85281 is not found. While 56065 is found.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (double, hash, file, read) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: If you need to get mutiple lines, you would use some sort of looping mechanism (like a `while()` loop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the other two answers point out you have to use `std::getline`, but this is how I would do it:

```c++
if (std::getline(is, zipcode, ',') &&
    std::getline(is, city,   ',') &&
    std::getline(is, state))
{
    d.zipCode = std::stoi(zipcode);
}
```

The only real change I made is that I encased the extractions within an `if` statement so you can check if these reads succeeded. Moreover, in order for this to be done easily (you wouldn't want to type the above out for every `Data` object), you can put this inside a function.

You can overload the `>>` operator for the `Data` class like so:

```c++
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Data& d)
{
    std::string zipcode;
    if (std::getline(is,  zipcode, ',') &&
        std::getline(is, d.city,   ',') &&
        std::getline(is, d.state))
    {
        d.zipCode = std::stoi(zipcode);
    }

    return is;
}
```

Now it becomes as simple as doing:

```c++
Data d;

if (std::cin >> d)
{
    std::cout << "Yes! It worked!";
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert that zipcode into integers even if, let's say, the zip code is M3M05? I imagine it would involve converting to ASCII values right?

Comment: @user3399575 What exactly would the integer representation of "M3M05" be? What exactly do you want to convert that to?

Comment: A number. Whatever that number is would depend on the zipcode. If the zipcode were "B3H2E8", then I expect the conversion to an integer would be different than that of M3M05.

Comment: @user3399575 So you basically want to "hash" the value. You would use `std::hash` for that (i.e `d.zipCode = std::hash<std::string>()(zipcode)`). It returns a value of `std::size_t` so you might also  want to change the type of `zipCode` to that as well.

Comment: @user3399575 No problem. :) Could you also click the checkmark please? =]

Comment: Question: how can you stop it at a blank line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getline function from `<string>` like this:

```
string str;                      // This will store your tokens
ifstream file("data.txt");

while (getline(file, str, ',')   // You can have a different delimiter
{
     // Process your data

}
```

You can also use stringstream:

```
stringstream ss(line);           // Line is from your input data file
while (ss >> str)                // str is to store your token
{
     // Process your data here
}
```

It's just a hint. Hope it helps you.

Comment: The `std::stringstream` example doesn't delimit on commas.

Comment: of course not. It takes out spaces from a line and break it into tokens that can be processed afterwards.

Comment: But he was looking for it to stop extracting on newlines, not just spaces.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is function `std::getline`

For example

```
std::string s;
std::getline( YourFileStream, s, ',' );
```

To convert a string to int you can use function `std::stoi`

Or you can read a whole line and then use std::istringstream to extract each data with the same function std::getline. For example

```
Data d = {};

std::string line;

std::getline( YourFileStream, line );

std::istringstream is( line );

std::string zipCode;

std::getline( is, zipCode, ',' );

d.zipCode = std::stoi( zipCode );

std::getline( is, d.city, ',' );
std::getline( is, d.state, ',' );
```

Comment: So does this mean that first chunk before the comma would be stored in the string s? In this case, it would be the zip code?

Comment: @user3399575 No it does not. As I said you need to convert the string to an object of type int. See my updated post.

Comment: Is this basically for just one line of the code? How would I make sure it goes onto the next line?